# I can't seem to link to the desired .lib file, resulting in an unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have inherited a VC++ solution and from one project (named "IntersonWinDriver") I'm trying to link to a .lib file that is generated by a different project (named "Utility").  I noticed that in a different project, named "MasterVu", I found "Utility.lib" included among the linker command line options.

In order to duplicate this for the IntersonWinDriver project, under the properties window I selected Configuration Properties->C/C++->General.  I added the folder containing the code for the Utility project under the "Additional Include Directories" option.  I then added the Utility project as one of the project dependencies for IntersonWinDriver.

The problem is that when I look at the linker command line options, I don't see any reference to Utility.lib as with the MasterVu project.  I could manually add a reference to Utility.lib under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, but I would rather not.  What am I missing here?

As you may guess, I'm getting an unresolved external symbol error due to any reference in IntersonWinDriver to code written under the Utility project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...I see that under Common Properties->Framework and References I can add the Utility project.  Now I feel silly for asking this question too soon...